# VBA Reference lost Selected after close Application

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I create Vbaproject that need to select more reference beside default reference of Excel VBA.

Everything work fine. However, when I save and close workbook. All Reference it reset to default choice, cause my code to error of missing reference.

I use office 365. Anyone have face with this problem? I google but still no help with this issue.

Comment: Look at [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx), does that help narrow your issue down (or even solve it)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have passed through that page, however that is not my problem. I am not missing of reference but it not keep been selected after I close excel.